# Reference for symplectic structures on schemes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, complex-manifolds, derived-algebraic-geometry

My original goal was to read the PTVV paper *Shifted Symplectic Structures* https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3209v4.pdf. I was quickly humbled!

Being told the theory ought to generalize symplectic structures on algebraic varieties and schemes I was unable to find a clear reference for these structures. I could get a hold of a paper or talk here and there giving some definition, but nothing futher.

Comment: There are expositions about deformation quantization in the contexts of schemes https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0106006v1.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0310399.pdf . But instead I would suggest studying a little bit of Lie $\infty$-algebroids, symplectic groupoids and all this in the DG context (or A_{\infty} DG context). Maybe studying the basics of noncommutative geometry in the DG context will also help (for instance, https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506603v1.pdf). The base field is not so important. Once you know for R, you know for C and, then, you know for every field of characteristic zero.

Comment: From Pantev result: moduli spaces of sheaves on Calabi-Yau manifolds admit shifted symplectic structures. So the question is that moduli spaces of sheaves on Kahler-Einstein manifolds admit shifted symplectic structures. ? https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10240-013-0054-1

Comment: Definition: A symplectic form on a smooth scheme over some base ring $k$ of characteristic zero is the datum of a closed 2-form $ω$ on $X$, which is required to be non-degenerate, i.e. it induces an isomorphism $Θ_ω:T_{X/k}→Ω^1_{X/k}$ between the tangent and cotangent sheaves on $X$. In the context of derived Artin stacks, the cotangent sheaf is replaced by the cotangent complex $L_{X/k}$; due to L. Illusie, idea

Comment: Second definition:The $p$-forms on the derived stack $X$ are then naturally defined as sections of $Λ^pL_{X/k}$, and more generally, elements in $H^n(X,Λ^pL_{X/k})$ are called $p$-forms of degree $n$ on $X$. The notion of closed $p$-forms on  $X$ is highly non-trivial.

Comment: The main difficulty is about the existence of shifted symplectic structures on derived stacks. There is few result of it.

Comment: The existence of a holomorphic symplectic structure on  Fano scheme $F(Y) $ of lines on a cubic fourfold $ Y,$ confirmed by Beauville and studied by Dimitri Markushevich also see http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM2003v067n01ABEH000421

Comment: The old question was that the moduli space $ \mathcal M_{X,P}$ of torsion free sheaves on $X$ with Hilbert polynomial $P$ which are generically simple $\mathcal A$-modules( as a sheaf of Azumaya algebras.) is symplectic? Ulrich confirmed it in the case when $X$ is $K3$-surface or Abelian variety.

Comment: Tyurin, generalized the result of S. Mukai on vector bundles on $K3$ surfaces to the case of regular algebraic surfaces $S$ with $p_g>0$ to construct a symplectic structure. See http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM1989v033n01ABEH000818

Comment: @HassanJolany Why does one expect moduli spaces of sheaves on an (algebraic) Kahler-Einstein manifold to have shifted symplectic structure?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dear past life Jacob,

Find a specific geometric problem that this stuff solves, which you think is interesting, and then you will find yourself magically learning it. For you, this problem was extending Donaldson-Thomas theory to Calabi-Yau 4-folds. Even in the Calabi-Yau 3-fold case, shifted symplectic structures show Behrend's notion of symmetric obstruction theory comes from a secret $-1$-shifted symplectic structure (this amazed you).

First read Behrend's paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507523) introducing symmetric obstruction theories, then possibly Joyce's paper on derived critical loci and DT3 invariants, and the Joyce-Borisov/Cao-Leung papers (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.00690.pdf /https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7659.pdf) on DT4 invariants. At that point you will not be able to sleep until you read PTVV.